# need to automate the RDLC reporting through SSIS script task?

Tags: asp.net, ssis

Currently I'm calling RDLC report in asp.net application, where .rdlc is calling and we passing a data source and report in generated as PDF, the entire process initiate on a BUTTON click and report is generate.

Now this process need to automate and report should generate on Monday morning.

There is some suggestion come out that we can use SSIS Script Task and we can call external DLL and can call .rdlc file too to generate the report and then we can schedule SSIS package?

I never having experience on SSIS side, need your suggestion and how to do that, if there is possibilities? Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SSRS to schedule the report to run.  No need for ASP.net or SSIS, SSRS has scheduling built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSRS subscription to send the report. If you really want the SSIS to send the report. you can do the following.

1. Create the report in SSRS
2. Deploy the report into report server
3. Create the SSIS package
4. Drag your Script task into the package.

You could use the following code snippet to send SSRS report using SSIS.

You should create some of the SSIS variables to store the report and render information.

1. RenderExtension ==> pdf
2. RenderFileName  ==> Name of the file you want write
3. RenderFormat    ==> PDF
4. RenderOutputPath==> Location to write the file
5. SSRSConnection  ==>
   `http://localhost/ReportServer/reportexecution2005.asmx` [Location of
   your report services]
6. SSRSFolderName  ==> Folder name of the report you deployed
7. SSRSReportName  ==> Name of the report

In the following snippet.

```
public void Main()
        {
            var rExtension = Dts.Variables["RenderExtension"].Value.ToString();
            var rFileName = Dts.Variables["RenderFileName"].Value.ToString();
            var rFormat = Dts.Variables["RenderFormat"].Value.ToString();
            var rOutputPath = Dts.Variables["RenderOutputPath"].Value.ToString();
            var ssrsConnection = Dts.Variables["SSRSConnection"].Value.ToString();
            var ssrsFolderName = Dts.Variables["SSRSFolderName"].Value.ToString();
            var ssrsReportName = Dts.Variables["SSRSReportName"].Value.ToString();

            ReportExecutionService rs=new ReportExecutionService();

            Byte[] results;

            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string mimetype = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;
            Warning[] warnings = null;
            string[] streamId = null;
            string deviceInfo = null;

            rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            rs.Url = ssrsConnection;

            try
            {
                var reportpath = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", ssrsFolderName, ssrsReportName);
                rs.LoadReport(reportpath, null);

                //Adding Parameters
                //Commenting the following line Till we test the functionality
                ParameterValue[] paramValues = new ParameterValue[4];

                ParameterValue paramValue = new ParameterValue();

                paramValue.Name = "ReportParamName";
                paramValue.Value = "X,Y,Z";

                paramValues[0] = paramValue;

                rs.SetExecutionParameters(paramValues, "en-US");

                results = rs.Render(rFormat, deviceInfo, out extension, out mimetype, out encoding, out warnings, out streamId);

                var filewithdatetime = string.Format("{0}_{1}",rFileName,DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_hhmmss"));

                string path = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}.{2}", rOutputPath, filewithdatetime, rExtension);

                MessageBox.Show(path);

                using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(path))
                {
                    stream.Write(results, 0, results.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```